# octave set axis step width consistent when resize window

Tags: octave

I want to use **drawRect**( [0 0 60 60] ) to draw a square.
But the step size of x- and y-axis change when I resize the window:
[image] 
[image]

And both of them don't "look like" square.

So, is there any method to set the x- and y-axis **step width** consistent? No matter how I resize the window?

```
Here is the result using @Dan's solution: axis( ..., "equal" )
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: That's just how the figures work in Octave. When you resize, it will not change the axis limits but rather the size of the axes on the screen. You can try `axis equal` to force it to be square, but this won't stop a user from resizing it again afterwards

Comment: @Dan That's a good solution! Could you post it again as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `axis("equal")`. From [the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Axis-Configuration.html) this will

> Force x distance to equal y-distance.

Comment: Let me add the result that used your solution.